# Python different behavour from comand line and php call

Tags: php, python, unicode

I'm using a small python 3.4 script that works great when called from comand line, but throws an exception when called from PHP script. Here's the php code for running python:

```
$cmd = 'python3 ./realty_parser_frontend.py';
$outputfile = 'log';
$pidfile = 'pid';

exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

The exact error is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The thing is i don't get that error when running the script directly and have no idea where the problem could be...

Comment: The webserver environment may have different locale settings (`LC_ALL` and `LANG`) than an interactive shell; which Python derives its encoding behaviour from.

Comment: What role plays encoding in PHP and how it is done? Seems to be a error that non-ascii characters are tried to be encoded by ascii codec...

Comment: If you just print the string created by sprintf, what do you see? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yep, sprintf gives python3 ./realty_parser_frontend.py > log 2>&1 & echo $! >> pid

Comment: And it gives the same result as running from php - same error